# Angular 2+ setTimeout()

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout

I am new to Angular 2. I want to use `setTimeout()` in `app.component.ts`. I tried referring many other post but nothing works for me.

Below is the code I was trying to do.

**app.component.ts**

```js
catchError() {
    if (navigator.onLine) {
        console.log("connected");
        this.displayNetworkError = false;
    } else {
        console.log("Disconnected");
        this.displayNetworkError = true;
    }
};

internetConnection() {
    setTimeout(this.catchError(), 2000);
};
```

**Please help me with some examples.**

Comment: `setTimeout(() => this.catchError(), 2000)`; you pass something *callable*, not something *called*.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout requires a function and a duration in miliseconds. Normally in javascript you would pass a function like setTimeout(function() {}, 1000).but in typescript you can use lambda expressions such as setTimeout(() => {}, 1000)

Comment: What you called lambda is called "Arrow function" and they are available in pure javascript of new verions, not only typescript.

Comment: I am trying this but its getting called only once

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {this.internetConnection();}, 1000);
  }

internetConnection(){
            if(navigator.onLine){
              console.log("connected");
            }
            else{
              console.log("Disconnected");
            }
   }

Answer (score 0):

You are execurting the funtion catchError when writing **this.catchError()**

The first Argument of setTimeout needs to be a function
so just use **this.catchError** instead of **this.catchError()**